Proving $\Theta \colon \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow T$ is covering map and image of $\Phi$ is homeomorphic to Mobius strip
I came across the following problem.

Let $R > r > 0$, consider the Torus imbedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as $T = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid (\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} - R)^{2} + z^{2} = r^{2}\}$. Now consider the following map: \begin{equation*}\Theta \colon \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow T \colon (\phi, \theta) \mapsto ((R + r\cos(\theta))\cos(\phi), (R+ r\cos(\theta))\sin(\phi), r\sin(\theta))\end{equation*} Prove that $\Theta$ is a covering map.

I have difficulty choosing an evenly covered neighbourhood $U$ of a point $(x, y, z) \in T$. I know that the torus is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ by a longitudinal circle and essentially rotating a meridian circle around it, I thought the intuition behind the choice might be related to this.

Consider the map \begin{equation*}\Phi \colon \mathbb{R} \times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} \colon (\phi, t) \mapsto t\Theta(\phi, \frac{\phi}{2}) + (1-t)\Theta(\phi, \frac{\phi}{2} + \pi). \end{equation*} Show that the image of $\Phi$ is homeomorphic to the Mobius strip.

It would suffice to describe how they are homeomorphic, I think it might be related to how we think of the Mobius strip as $M = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]/\sim$ where $(0, t) \sim (1, 1-t)$ but other than that I'm stuck.
Any help is appreciated.

These are two different questions.
Q1.
It is well-known that $S^1 \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to $T$ via
$$H : S^1 \times S^1 \to T, H((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = ((R+rx_2)x_1,(R+rx_2)y_1,ry_2) .$$
See my answer to Parametrization of torus and homeomorphism to $S^1 \times S^1$ and note that the above $H$ is obtained from the homeomorphism $h$ occuring in the link by a coordinate switch on $S^1 \times S^1$ (i.e. $H(z_1, z_2) = h(z_2,z_1)$).
Since $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) = (\cos t, \sin t) = e^{it}$, is a covering map, also $p \times p : \mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to S^1 \times S^1$ is one. We have $\Theta = h \circ(p \times p)$, thus $\Theta$ is a covering map.
Observe that $\Theta$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ in both variables.
Q2.
Let us understand what $\Phi$ does.
The torus $T$ is the disjoint union of the circles $S_{z_1} = H(\{z_1 \} \times S^1)$, $z_1 = (x_1,y_1) \in S^1$, which are contained in the two-dimensional linear subspace $L_{z_1} \subset \mathbb R^3$ spanned by $(z_1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. The center of $S_{z_1}$ is $c_{z_1} = (Rz_1,0)$, its radius is $r$. Clearly $\Theta$ maps $\{\phi \} \times \mathbb R$ to $S_{p(\phi)}$. In fact, it is easily checked that
$$\Theta(\phi,\theta) - c_{p(\phi)} = r( p(\phi)\cos \theta, \sin \theta) . \tag{1}
$$
The points $\Theta(\phi,\theta)$ and $\Theta(\phi,\theta + \pi)$ are antipodal in $S_{p(\phi)}$ which means that $\Theta(\phi,\theta + \pi) - c_{p(\phi)} = -(\Theta(\phi,\theta) - c_{p(\phi)})$. To see this, we observe that $\cos (\theta + \pi) = - \cos \theta$ and $\sin (\theta + \pi) = - \sin \theta$ and use $(1)$.
Hence $\Phi(\{\phi\} \times [0,1])$ is the diameter $\ell_\phi$ of $S_{p(\phi)}$ connecting the antipodal points $\Theta(\phi,\frac \phi 2)$ and $\Theta(\phi,\frac \phi 2 + \pi)$. The map $\Phi: \{\phi\} \times [0,1] \to \ell_\phi$ is a homeomorphism.
We claim that $\ell_\phi = \ell_{\phi + 2\pi}$. To see this, we observe that $\Theta(\phi +2\pi,\frac{\phi +2\pi}{2}) = \Theta(\phi, \frac \phi 2 + \pi)$ and $\Theta(\phi +2\pi,\frac{\phi +2\pi}{2}+\pi) = \Theta(\phi,\frac \phi 2 + 2\pi) = \Theta(\phi,\frac \phi 2)$.
This shows that the image of $\Phi$ is nothing else than $M = \Phi([0,2\pi] \times [0,1])$. We therefore have a surjective map $\Phi : [0,2\pi] \times [0,1] \to M$. By construction the sets $\ell_\phi = \Phi(\{\phi\} \times [0,1])$ and $\ell_{\phi'} = \Phi(\{\phi'\} \times [0,1])$ are disjoint when $\phi - \phi' < 2\pi$ (because $S_{p(\phi)}$ and $S_{p(\phi')}$ are disjoint). Thus $\Phi : [0,2\pi] \times [0,1] \to M$ is a quotient map identifying points in $\{0\} \times [0,1]$ with points in $\{2\pi\} \times [0,1]$. By periodicity we get
$$\Phi(2\pi,t) = t\Theta(2\pi,\pi) + (1-t)\Theta(2\pi,\pi + \pi) = t\Theta(0,\pi) + (1-t)\Theta(0,0) = \Phi(0,1-t).$$
This shows that $M$ is homeomorphic to the Möbius strip.
